# Solving linear system using Python with numba and CUDA

Tags: python, numpy, cuda

I am trying to solve a linear system using numba with GPU processing using CUDA.

I have installed all the relevant packages and tested it so it seems that my GPU and CUDA etc is set up properly.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import time

from numba import vectorize, cuda


@vectorize(['float64(float64, float64)'], target='cuda')
def solver(A, b):
    return np.linalg.solve(A, b)


def main():

    A = np.random.rand(100, 100).astype(np.float64)
    b = np.random.rand(100, 1).astype(np.float64)

    start = time.time()
    C = solver(A, b)
    vector_add_time = time.time() - start

    print("Took " + str(vector_add_time) + " seconds to solve")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Commenting the `@vectorize...` line, the code runs fine. However, when I try to do it with numba and cuda, I get a long list of errors, where I think he most relevant one is:

```
raise TypingError(msg)
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
np.linalg.solve() only supported for array types
```

I assume the problem is that `numpy.linalg.solve` does not accept the data types required by cuda.

Am I correct in assuming this? Are there other data types that will work?

In [this](https://github.com/lebedov/scikit-cuda/blob/master/skcuda/linalg.py) example problem, the same data type is passed to the function, so I think the problem lies with numpy.linalg.

Comment: Thank you Robert. I was just using a 'toy' problem to start to learn the cuda work flow. I suppose I didn't choose a good example.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I correct in assuming this?

No

> Are there other data types that will work?

No

The problem here is that you cannot use `numpy.linalg` in code which is targeted to run on the numba GPU backend.

Comment: Thank you. As pointed out by someone who subsqeuently deleted their comment (?) my 'toy' problem doesn't make sense in any way, but more generally: will only objects/methods/functions from the numba/cuda suite work? From the example problem linked in my question, it seems like cuda can work with the `ndarray`, so I assume that I can do computations with some numpy functions inside a numba/cuda-wrapped function?